# How to disable weighted interpolation GLSL? (how to just average the vertex values)

Tags: glsl

I would like to have the normal vector of the fragments on a single face in my mesh be the same for all fragments.

Due to the way my engine works I cannot enable provoking vertices. Don't bring them up in your reply, i've looked into it already.

I'd like all fragments to take the three values of that face and average them without weighting, interpolation, etc.

To clarify:
I want a variable output from the vertex shader to the fragment shader with strict averaging, no interpolation. Is there some qualifier or technique I could use in OpenGL to achieve this?

I would be even happier if i could just get the values from each vertice and interpolate them myself, I have some awesome shader ideas if I can!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers

Comment: Apparently I'm not the first person who wanted to edit this answer to change the URL to an actual link, but no one seems eager enough to approve the edits, so I'm just going to put the clickable link here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Interpolation_qualifiers